How to force only shipping & payment method to be a radio button
I have a unique situation where we only allow 1 form of shipping and 1 form of payment for a particular brand of products. If this brand of products is in the cart, the customer can only pick up and can only pay via bank transfer.
When both of these are the only options and are selected by default, users tend to ignore it and place their orders, leading to more work due to needing to call the customer to follow up on the order.
Is there a way to make the only shipping and payment methods remain as radio buttons to be selected?
I've tried implementing the below code to not select one by default, but due to the shipping method not being a radio button, this doesn't work, as well as the payment method code not working either.
add_filter( 'pre_option_woocommerce_default_gateway' . '__return_false', 99 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_chosen_method', '__return_false', 99);

